# Convert specific columns to rows with some other columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

Hi have this query in SQL Server 2008R2

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Type    Quantity
7       191     95      94      2
7       333     58      94      1
32      656     58      94      1
7       191     95      95      4
7       333     58      95      1
32      656     58      95      2
```

I need to pivot putting Type as a column and quantity as a value, keeping the other columns as well doing a group by, and having this result:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 [94]    [95]
7       191     95      2       4
7       333     58      1       1
32      656     58      1       2
```

Comment: So what have you tried and what problem did you have? Looks like a bog standard `PIVOT` to me?

Comment: trying to create the query, no problem, I know how to do it now with the post of bluefeet, thanks!